# Abbreviated first person singular ending

Tags: окончания

I noticed an acceptable alternative of the first person singular verb ending.
I don't know if

1. this is just an abbreviation or changes the meaning
2. is associated to aspect,
3. is associated to verbs of motion,
4. has analogues in other persons

e.g.

я бегу  - я бегаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are 2 different verbs that form one of the pair of the verbs of motion.

**Бежа́ть-бéгать**

**Бежа́ть:** Я бегу, ты бежи́шь, он (она́, оно́) бежи́т, мы бежи́м, вы бежи́те, они́ бегу́т

**Бе́гать:** Я бе́гаю, ты бе́гаешь, он (она́, оно́) бе́гает, мы бе́гаем, вы бе́гаете, они́ бе́гают

Being the verbs of motion without prefixes, these verbs are both imperfective.The **first** one in the pair, "бежать" means **"to run in one direction".** The **second** one in the pair, бéгать means **"to run somewhere and then return", "to run without any direction"** pr "to run regularly".

All the verbs of motion work like that, the first verb means "to go, fly, swim, run, carry, etc. in one direction" and the second one, in two directions, way and back:

идти́-ходи́ть: go on foot
плыть-пла́вать: swim
лете́ть-лета́ть: fly
е́хать-е́здить: go on transport, ride
нести́-носи́ть: carry something on foot
везти́-вози́ть: carry something on transport
вести-води́ть: lead somebody

Comment: so "бегу" is first person singular of the verb Бежа́ть. Thanks

Comment: Try to always remember that stems for building past/infinitive and for building present tense form are, generally, slightly different. "Бежать" is an irregular verb, so better just memorize it. The verbs **есть, дать, бежать, хотеть** are irregular: these four verbs and all their derivatives (захотеть, убежать, предать, съесть, наесться...) form their conjugated personal forms in a unique way that does not conform to any of two usual patterns (Е-conjugation and И-conjugation)